# passing .php array into a javascript code jquery/ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

At the moment i have this piece of javascript code:

```
//Display custom confirm box and delete multiple message

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete_button-multiple").click(function () {
        //Get message id as variable
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        //Display custom Confirm box  
        jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?', '', function (r) {
            if (r == true) { //initiate delete message if agreed

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete-mail_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function () {
                        window.location = "mail_inbox.php";
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });

    });
});


delete-mail_ajax.php:

if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$id = mysql_escape_String($id);
$sql = "delete FROM mail WHERE mail_id='$id'";
mysql_query( $sql);
}
```

This is a working code for deleting only one mail item.
I wrote the following code to delete multiple messages from checkboxes:

```
        //Multiple delete mail
        if(!empty($_POST['message'])){ 
        $list_mail = $_POST['message'];
        foreach ($list_mail as $messageID){    
        $sql = "delete FROM mail WHERE mail_id='$messageID'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        //deletion complete, refresh the page
        header("Location: mail_inbox.php");
        }
        }//end delete multiple
```

The difficulty i'm having is changing the working code above to incorporate the multiple selection, and deletion, of selected mails.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated

-Callum

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? I didn't really got that... Selection? I would suggest to use checkboxes.

Comment: I am using checkboxes. the issue was that i wasn't sure how to pass the array through the jquery function and then into ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using checkboxes, your code would look something like:

```
var messages = new Array();
$("input[name='mail_items[]']:checked").each(function() {
   messages.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete-mail_ajax.php",
   data: { message: messages }  //jQuery should translate this to an array that PHP should understand
   cache: false,
   ...
});
```

You may need to json_decode the input to the $_POST['message'] variable, but I'd do a var_dump() on the stuff first just to make sure what PHP is doing in the background. Can't check at the moment, sorry.

Comment: thank you for this.
i understand everything apart from the var_dump() and json_decode part?

Comment: That's on the PHP side.  Just as a check, do a var_dump($_POST['message']).  If you see it as an array, you're in business.  If you see it as a string, you'll have to throw it through the json_decode function to make it an array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have trouble submitting the form via Ajax? There is a neat plugin that does that for you: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: the problem i'm having is, trying to pass the array to the javascript and then to ajax